# Graph between the gradient of a straight line and its angle to the horizontal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to plot a graph between the gradient of a straight line ($y$ = $m$$x$, of which $m$ is the gradient), and it's angle it makes between itself, and the $x$-axis.

To find the angle, I made two vectors, $p_1$= (1, $m$), and $p_2$= (1, 0). With these two vectors, I calculated the angle using the dot product $θ$ = arccos($p_1$ ⋅ $p_2$ /      |$p_1$||$p_2$|)

I plotted the graph (https://imgur.com/R1qaUKV) of which the x axis is the gradient, and the y axis is $θ$ in radians.

I need the equation of this graph, but I don't know how to derive it. I tried to solve it simultaneously, but I my methods didn't work. (I am sorry about the bad formatting)

Answer (score 1):

There is another way of obtaining the angle between the line and the x-axis which immediately gives you the expression of the function you're looking for. The value of $y=mx$ at $x=1$ is precisely the gradient $m$. In the graph you can now see a right triangle between the points $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,m)$. Using the inverse of the tangent function now immediately gives you the angle you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the definition $ m= \tan \alpha $ direct.

If $m$ is plotted on y-axis, we have a tan trig function graph.

If $m=\tan \alpha $ is plotted on x-axis as you have, you got an arctan trig function as an inverse function of the above. Max asymptotic value is $+\pi/2.$

You can also graph $m$ negative on the x-axis.